# get only child id from multi level array in PHP

Tags: php, recursion

I have multi level categories array.
i only want to get child ID's, if parent don't have child. then return that parent id as well

```
id   parent_id    name
1      0          fashion
2      1          women
3      1          men
4      2          jeans
5      2          skirts
6      5          short skirts
7      5          long skirts
8      0          Home & entertainment
```

I tried this fucntion.

```
function buildtree($src_arr, $parent_id = 0, $tree = array()){
       foreach($src_arr as $idx => $row){
           if($row['parent_id'] == $parent_id){
               foreach($row as $k => $v)
                   $tree[$row['id']][$k] = $v;
               unset($src_arr[$idx]);
               $tree[$row['id']]['children'] = self::buildtree($src_arr, $row['id']);
           }
       }
       ksort($tree);
       return $tree;
   }
```

But it also gives me all parents id's.

desired outcome with id ( i am typing name for easy understanding)

```
array(
 [0]  = men 
 [1]  = jeans
 [2]  = short skirts
 [3]  = long skirts
 [4]  = home & entertainment 
)
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Please write your array as array. and one another point for what reason you taged mysql ? do you get this array from table ?

Comment: does it matter? do you understand the question??

Comment: of course, if you select it from table, it is possible to do it with query.

Comment: now it is not clear, at least for me. you want to check if any record has child, then select it? the desired out put shows that if any `id` is existed as `parent_id` then get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple `where` clause with `not in` logic will help you select the children, then the parents that have no children.

```
select c.id, c.name
from categories c
where c.id not in (select parent_id from categories order by id desc)
```

Which gives a result set of

```
+----+----------------------+
| id | name                 |
+----+----------------------+
|  3 | men                  |
|  4 | jeans                |
|  6 | long skirts          |
|  7 | short skirts         |
|  8 | home & entertainment |
+----+----------------------+
5 rows in set
```

#### [See SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8fd009/5/0)

Comment: Why so complicated? This gives the desired result: select c.id, c.name from categories c where c.id not in (select parent_id from categories order by id desc)

Comment: ...no clue, aha! I'll correct my answer to make it less complicated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Done in PHP you can use this function, which gives you a flat array with all edge childs based on a given parent_id. If you want to check a whole database table sql-only is the better option.

```
function getchildren($src_arr, $parent_id = 0) 
{ 
    $allchildren = array();

    foreach($src_arr as $idx => $row){ 
        if($row['parent_id'] == $parent_id){ 
            $children = static::getchildren($src_arr, $row['id']);
            if ($children) { 
                $allchildren = array_merge($allchildren, $children);                 
            } else { 
                $allchildren[] = $row;
            } 
        } 
    } 

    return $allchildren;
}
```